# Https between my docker containers and my local network computer, later deploy to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: docker, https, raspberry-pi

I have two Docker images that I'm developing in Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET, Razor Pages, want to run on a Raspberry Pi. One is a website that calls the other using REST.

When testing in through Visual Studio running docker-compose I get the following error when I try to POST from one container to another:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of
> errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

I've been trying to use mkcert to ease all the troubles of certificates and trust that I'm running into but I'm still confused, and the setup is getting more and more complex, certificates proliferate with my attempts.

I understand that there is a ASP NET developer certificate but whether or not I can use that when I deploy to the Raspberry Pi, I don't know.

Is it really going to be this hard to get HTTPS on my local network between a computer and some docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested an approach between 2 Docker containers in my network - but should also work from any client in the network to the a server hosted in a container.

Create the certificate on the PI hosting the server container:

```sh
mkdir -p /tmp/certs
export CERTPASS=$(pwgen)
echo $CERTPASS >/tmp/certs/myservercert.txt
openssl req -x509 \
    -passout env:CERTPASS \
    -subj "/CN=server.my.net" \
    -newkey rsa:4096 \
    -keyout /tmp/certs/familyboardkey.pem \
    -out /tmp/certs/myservercert.pem \
    -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export \
    -out /tmp/certs/myservercert.pfx \
    -inkey /tmp/certs/familyboardkey.pem \
    -in /tmp/certs/myservercert.pem \
    -passin env:CERTPASS \
    -passout env:CERTPASS
openssl pkcs12 -in /tmp/certs/myservercert.pfx \
    -passin env:CERTPASS \
    -clcerts -nokeys -out /tmp/certs/myservercert.crt
```

Start the server with mounted certificate folder:

```sh
docker run -d \
    --name myserver \
    -p 5001:5001 \
    -p 5000:5000 \
    -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="$(cat /tmp/certs/myservercert.txt)" \
    -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path="/tmp/certs/myservercert.pfx" \
    --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/certs/,target=/tmp/certs/ \
    --restart always \
    myserver
```

For my server https://github.com/KaiWalter/familyboard-aspnetcore I created this simple test console client:

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var certificateName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CERTNAME");

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certificateName));
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var responseHttp = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<DateFormatInfo>("http://server.my.net:5000/api/calendar/dateformatinfo");
Console.WriteLine($"MonthNames: {responseHttp.MonthNames.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"WeekDayNames: {responseHttp.WeekDayNames.Count}");

var responseHttps = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<DateFormatInfo>("https://server.my.net:5001/api/calendar/dateformatinfo");
Console.WriteLine($"MonthNames: {responseHttps.MonthNames.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"WeekDayNames: {responseHttps.WeekDayNames.Count}");

public class DateFormatInfo
{
    public List<string> MonthNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> WeekDayNames { get; set; }
}
```

The line `handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;` is required to overcome `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot` for the self-signed certificate.

```sh
docker run -it --network host \
    -e CERTNAME="/tmp/certs/myservercert.crt" \
    --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/certs/,target=/tmp/certs/ \
    myclient
```

Does this make sense for you?